# Android - OnPreferenceChangeListener - Doesn't matter what I return

Tags: android

I have a PreferenceScreen and a PreferenceFragment.
I apply this OnPreferenceChangeListener to one of the prefs.

```
findPreference("example_text").setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                    if(((String)newValue).equals("dd")) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Doesn't matter what I return. The value saves anyway.

Not what the doc says

```
boolean True to update the state of the Preference with the new value.
```

Am I missing something?
If not, then it's probably some silly mistake.

Comment: This only works if you are updating the preference value through the UI. It does not do anything if you are modifying the `SharedPreferences` directly. Are you doing the latter?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the auto-generated function `bindPreferenceSummaryToValue` in the SettingsActivity was already setting an `onPreferenceChangeListener`, so that was causing the confusion in the app.

Thanks for your time